# Backing up data volume containers off machine

Tags: docker

when reading this:

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

Am I correct in the thinking that tar file they're referencing is still isolated in containers, and these examples aren't demonstrating anyway to preserve state after a machine loss?

Or is there a mental leap I'm not making with due to my ignorance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker run --volumes-from dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup \
  ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

> Here:
>
> - we’ve launched a new container and mounted the volume from the `dbdata` container.
> - We’ve **then mounted a local host directory as `/backup`**.
> - Finally, we’ve passed a command that uses tar to backup the contents of the `dbdata` volume to a `backup.tar` file inside our `/backup` directory.
>     When the command completes and the container stops we’ll be left with a backup of our `dbdata` volume.

So:

> Am I correct in the thinking that tar file they're referencing is still isolated in containers

No, it is on pwd (on the host hard drive current working directory), since pwd was mounted as `/backup` in the ubuntu container where the tar occurred.

An ls of the current working directory will list `backup.tar`, once the container ubuntu exits.

Comment: ok, thats what i originally thought, however my tar file isn't showing up and another container was made.  However I can see tar running, but no tar file on pwd.

Comment: Asked follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192786/docker-data-volume-container-i-cant-seem-to-get-to-backup