# Docker data volume container. I can't seem to get to backup

Tags: docker

Reading these links:

1. https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes
2. [Backing up data volume containers off machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189965/backing-up-data-volume-containers-off-machine)

My understanding is I can take a data volume container and archive its backup.
However reading the first link I can't seem to get it to work.

```
docker create -v /sonatype-work --name sonatype-work sonatype/nexus /bin/true
```

I launch sonatype/nexus image in a container using:

```
--volumes-from sonatype-nexus
```

All good, after running nexus, i inspect the data volume, i can see the innards created, and stop and remove nexus and start again, all changes saved.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
f84abb054d2e        sonatype/nexus      "/bin/sh -c 'java   -"   22 seconds ago      Up 21 seconds       0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   nexus
1aea2674e482        sonatype/nexus      "/bin/true"              25 seconds ago      Created                                      sonatype-work
```

I want to now back up sonatype-work, but with no luck.

```
[root@ansible22 ~]# pwd
/root
[root@ansible22 ~]# docker run --volumes-from sonatype-work -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/sonatype-work-backup.tar /sonatype-work
tar: /backup/sonatype-work-backup.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have tried running as -u root, I also tried with:

```
/root/sonatype-work-backup.tar
```

When doing so, i can see it taring stuff, but I don't see the tar file.  Based on the example and my understanding I don't think thats right anyway.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Linux Version Info

```
Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two)
NAME=Fedora
VERSION="22 (Twenty Two)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=22
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 22 (Twenty Two)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:22"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=22
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=22
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL=https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy
VARIANT="Server Edition"
VARIANT_ID=server
Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two)
Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two)
```

Comment: Strange, this is exactly the procedure I follow with data volumes. Tried just  now with these Nexus containers and it works as well. Anything strange with the permissions in the current directory you're running from? How about if you use /tmp instead, like `docker run --volumes-from sonatype-work -v /tmp:/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/sonatype-work-backup.tar /sonatype-work` ?

Comment: I just tried in /tmp same error.  its a fresh install of fedora22 as root in /root, i wonder if its (that BLEEPING) selinux?

Comment: That's very possible/likely. Try adding the `:Z` to the `--volumes-from` i.e. `docker run --volumes-from sonatype-work -v $(pwd):/backup:Z ubuntu tar cvf /backup/sonatype-work-backup.tar /sonatype-work`. Another option is to run the container as privileged, i.e. with `--privileged=true`.

Comment: is privileged the same as `-u root`?

Comment: It goes a little further, in terms of providing extended access to devices and in how it interacts with AppArmor or SELinux. Some details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/. As noted in that page, it also enables things like "Docker in Docker" :) - http://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is related to selinux labelling. There are a couple of good Project Atomic pages on this:

[Docker and Linux](http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/docker-and-selinux/)

> The default type for a confined container process is svirt_lxc_net_t. This type is permitted to read and execute all files types under /usr and most types under /etc. svirt_lxc_net_t is permitted to use the network but is not permitted to read content under /var, /home, /root, /mnt … svirt_lxc_net_t is permitted to write only to files labeled **svirt_sandbox_file_t** and docker_var_lib_t. All files in a container are labeled by default as svirt_sandbox_file_t.

Then in [Using Volumes with Docker can Cause Problems with SELinux](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/):

> This will label the content inside the container with the exact MCS label that the container will run with, basically it runs `chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t -l s0:c1,c2 /var/db` where s0:c1,c2 differs for each container.

(In this case not `/var/db` but `/root`)

> If you volume mount a image with -v /SOURCE:/DESTINATION:z docker will automatically relabel the content for you to s0. If you volume mount with a Z, then the label will be specific to the container, and not be able to be shared between containers.

So either `z` or `Z` are suitable in this case but one might usually prefer `Z` for the isolation.

Comment: great thanks, nice info.  also to note for those that come here.  the same seems to apply if you want to restore the tar file to a container as well following docker's guidance here: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

Answer (score 0):

The reason I'm getting permission denied is because of selinux.  I am not sure why yet, but will edit this answer when/if I find out.  Disabling selinux and restarting, i was able to take a back up.

Comment: I think you can try with the `:Z` in the `-v` line. As of 1.7, Docker will add labels on the fly when this is used, see https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/5910

Comment: I turned selinux back on rebooted added the Z and it worked.  If you want to write something up as an answer I'll mark yours as the accepted.  I'd like to know more about it.  Thanks